# mySQL trigger - prevent insert won't work for multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert

*This is not another "how to prevent insert with triggers" thread. I have done my research and I found a couple of ways but unfortunately, they won't work in my case.*

I have a table in my database with a numeric column called "value". I want to cancel a new insert if its value is near the value of a previous insert. So here are my attempts:

*first try:*

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE ABS(new.val - val) <= 1) THEN
  SET new.val = null;
END IF
```

Results: It works well for one insert (throws an error and cancels the insert). However, for multiple inserts at once, all records are inserted (and the inserts that should be rejected have value 0).

*second try:*

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE ABS(new.val - val) <= 1) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
END IF
```

Results: Again, works well for one insert. But for multiple inserts at once, it will reject all inserts even if there is only one that should be rejected.

Any suggestions?

I hope I was clear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: By "multiple inserts at once", do you mean a single `INSERT` statement that inserts more than one row, or multiple concurrent sessions each inserting one row?

Comment: If `val` has a unique index on it - what if you changed `new.val` to an existing `val` where they're close? Would that still prevent all inserts, or would the non-existing `val` values go through? NOTE: you would still have an issue if multiple records in the data to insert have values that are too close. (Not making this an answer at this point - don't know MySQL well enough to know if it's a possibility. If it is, I'll convert).

Comment: @mustaccio I mean a single INSERT that inserts more than one row.

Comment: Then this is expected behaviour: if you issue `SIGNAL`, the entire statement is rolled back; if you `set new.val` to NULL, you insert NULL (I guess your client is messing with you by showing zeroes for NULL values).

Comment: @RDFozz unfortunately, it does not work. It prevents all inserts.

Comment: @mustaccio I see.. So do you know any solution for filtering the inserts and rejecting only some of them?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour: if you raise a `SIGNAL`, the entire statement is rolled back; if you set `new.val` to NULL, you insert NULL (I guess your client is messing with you by showing zeroes for NULL values).

You could work around this problem by not inserting ineligible records in the first place, something like this:

```
insert into test2 (val) select val from (
  -- values to insert
  select 1 as val union all 
  select 3
) i 
where not exists (
  select 1 from test2 t where abs(t.val - i.val) <= 1
)
```